# Styling CSS tables where display: table-row is used

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to style a CSS table to draw a grey box around every row, and alternate between grey/white background for each row.

```css
.table_row_line {
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section style="display: table;">
  <header class="table_row_line" style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
  </header>
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This does nothing to the styling.

I have tried wrapping the header in a div, which will allow me to style it, but it then stops acting like a table and the first header row stops aligning with the main content.

How can I style this css table?

Comment: why not using  <thead> and <tbody> tags  !

Comment: @adel  — They wouldn't be valid

Comment: Just for future reference `display:table-header-group;` is the equivalent of `thead` and `display:table-row-group;` is the equivalent of `tbody` and `display:table-footer-group;` is the equivalent of `tfoot`. You would still have to use border collapse in order to add borders to them anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the borders are collapsed, table rows don't have borders, they just hold the table cells (which can have borders) in place.

Set `border-collapse: collapse`.

```css
section {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table_row_line {
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section style="display: table;">
  <header class="table_row_line" style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">1</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">2</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">3</div>
  </header>
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">4</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">5</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">6</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

(Also consider if `display: table` is really the right approach, and ask if you would be better off with a real table or with flexbox or grid layout).

Comment: Thanks, that worked and may put me on the right track to doing what I want. I have tabulated financial data, I did intend on using tables from the outset, but after reading this https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/ I figured a CSS solution would be a better option.

Comment: @seventeen — Tabulated financial data sounds very much like a case for real tables. See the section "When To Use Tables" in the document you linked to.

Comment: thanks, but your solution worked, I added nth-child(odd) and have the exact appearance I needed.

Comment: Keep in mind that markup isn't about appearance. Think about how your data is going to be presented in a screen reader, or to a search engine.